# Ping Federate - Cache Control for Engine nodes

Tags: cache-control, pingfederate

I have identified the place where if you activate the cacheControl you will get the desired value in all the http requests. The file is the

> etc/webdefault.xml

one. I have activated the custom cacheControl value like this:

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>cacheControl</param-name>
  <param-value>no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0</param-value>
</init-param>
```

BUT it seems that these values are only being set if you are accessing the admin node (port 9999) and does not apply if you are 
accessing the engine node (port 9031).

Do you know if this is a know bug or am I missing something here?

Comment: I'd suggest presenting the problem that you are trying to solve, rather than presenting a broken method by which you believe to be able to solve a problem... By default, PingFederate has `no-store` and `no-cache`, making `must-revalidate` and `max-age=0` redundant. How can you revalidate something after 0 seconds if it was never cached or stored?

Comment: Hi. You can check the result out, I have used OWasp Zap:

`Whenever possible ensure the cache-control HTTP header is set with no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate; and that the pragma HTTP header is set with no-cache.`

Comment: I found the place. There is a war file that overwrites the webdefault.xml via a web.xml with the other values. Case closed.